# Environment variables in Docker

Tags: docker, environment-variables

I want to use a `.env-file` to describe my variables:

```
URL: $HOST
PORT: $PORT
MAIL = “test@test.be”
PASS = “test123"
```

I want to use the file in my container:

```
docker run --env-file myfile
```

But I want to replace the $HOST and $PORT in my file
Can I do something like this?

```
docker run --env-file myfile -e PORT="8080" -e "HOST=ec2-xxx"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is already supported, only thing is you need to make sure your ENV file is properly formatted:

```
$ cat myfile
URL= $HOST
PORT= $PORT
MAIL= “test@test.be”
PASS= “test123
```

Once your env-file is properly formatted, you could use the docker run command as follows:

```
$ docker run --env-file=myfile -e HOST=123.22 -e PORT=234 busybox env
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=0d543af16a70
URL= $HOST
PORT=234
MAIL= “test@test.be”
PASS= “test123
HOST=123.22
HOME=/root
```

> Please observe, in the above docker run command "busybox" is a
>   container and `env` is the command that gets executed on running the
>   above command. In your case, you may change the container name, and be
>   assured that the env variables are properly sent.

Comment: Is only the first line the command? (I understand that). But I don't understand the Path? Or are you running your container to show its env-variables?

Comment: First line is the command starting with docker and ending with env. Rest of the lines are the output.